# Filtro de dados em tempo real usando Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Estou construindo um sistema de comentários e gostaria que quando o usuário selecionasse o valor de um campo select, uma variável fosse enviada para uma página PHP com o valor selecionado, e a mesma retornaria os resultados dentro de uma div.

```
<form>
    <div class="campo">
        <label>Ordenar por: </label>
        <select id="ordenar" name="ordenar">
            <option>Relevância</option>
            <option>Mais Recente</option>
        </select>
    </div>                  
    <div class="campo">
        <label>Comentários apenas de: </label>
        <select id="filtroComentarios" name="filtroComentarios">
            <option>Professores</option>
            <option>Estudantes</option>
        </select>
    </div> 
</form>

<div id="comentarios"> </div>
//Div que recebe os comentários filtrados
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.campo select').on('change', function(){
  var valorSelecionado = $('.campo select').eq(0).val();
  var valorSelecionado2 = $('.campo select').eq(1).val();
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "pagina.php",
    data: {variavel: valorSelecionado, variavel2: valorSelecionado2} // variavel é o nome que você deve pegar no servidor.
  })
  .done(function( msg ) {
    $('#comentarios').text(msg);
    //ou $('#comentarios').html(msg);
  });
})
```

A partir daqui é só você usar $_POST no php para pegar o valor, filtrar e dar um echo ou algo assim no servidor com os comentários já formatados.

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, mas como eu faria para passar os dois selects ?

Comment: Editei a resposta, veja se funciona. São somente dois selects que pretende usar mesmo?

Comment: Cara, funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado mesmo!